# File Upload event context and javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, file-upload

I need to conditionally open the file upload dialog of:

```html
<input type="file" id="Upload">
```

based on the Ajax response from the server. The input element is hidden since I don't wish to show the default ugly file text box and button. So I have another element the the user click on to initiate the upload.

The following works fine from script where the event context is initiated by the user.

```js
$('#Upload').click();
```

but fails when the response of the Ajax call performs it. Now I know this is by design for Firefox and Chrome due to security concerns but in my case the user initiates the ajax call and the server is required to decide whether the conditions on the server are currently such that the upload should be allowed. If so I want to open the file upload dialog, otherwise I need to post a message stating that the action is not allowed for x reason (returned by the server).

The problem is that the Ajax callback is not in the user scripting context thus the .click() to open the file dialog (as designed) is not executed.

What else can be done to work around this problem? Is there a way to capture the user event context and reuse it for the callback of the Ajax call?

Comment: Can you post the code, please?

Comment: There is realy no code to show other than than "$('#Upload').click();" I need this code to work from the Ajax call back. Works from user event context but not from Ajax call back. If you can get that line of script to execute from the call back function then you have solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

To make a simple uploader with JQuery use this code

HTML

```
<form id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" id="Upload"></br>
    <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 0%"></div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Start Upload</button>
</form>
```

You select your file and after you confirm upload when you click on the button "Start Upload"

JQuery

```
$('#form').submit(function(){
    var data = new FormData(this);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: URL_TO_UPLOADER,
        data: data,
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData:false,
        beforeSend: function() {
            $(".progress-bar").width('0%');
        },
        xhr: function() {
            var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();

            // Upload progress
            xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(evt) {
                if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                    var percentComplete = (evt.loaded / evt.total) * 100;
                    $(".progress-bar").width(percentComplete+'%');
                }
            }, false);

            // Download progress
            xhr.addEventListener("progress", function(evt) {
                if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                    var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total * 100;
                    $find(".progress-bar").width(percentComplete+'%');
                }
            }, false);
            return xhr;
        },
        success: function(data) {
            alert("Success");
            // File Uploaded
        },
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("Error");
        },
    });
});
```

PATH_TO_UPLOADER is a url who receive the file.

Comment: I have already written all the code and it works except for the condition explained above. The only problem I am trying to resolve is how to open an upload dialog box programatically from the Ajax callback function.

Comment: To clarify. What I asked is trictly related to opening the file upload dialog not about the upload itself. I need to programatically open the file upload dialog based on the result of an Ajax callback function. This Ajax call back function is not the callback of the upload itself but a callback returning a value that determines if opening the upload dialog is allowed by the server imediately after the user tried to open it. If allowed I need to open the dialog otherwise I post a message why its not allowed.

Comment: If I understand your question, You need to use 2 ajax. One for check if the file is allowed to upload, second to upload the file in your server.
success: function(data) {
    // SECONT_AJAX
}
And I think, that is a bad solutions to tried if the file is allowed to upload like that. Make just a little test in js before start AJAX(like check file extension).

Comment: And if you want read the file, you can use [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FileReader)

Comment: The reason I need to do the check on the server is because I need to check if the file upload is allowed based on contractual agreements which reside in the database. The condition to allow a contract upload override has nothing to do with the file itself so it can not be done on the client side. It has to do with a contractual state which may no longer allow document changes thus no new contract can be uploaded. This state changes frequently and may be incorrect or unknown at render time and must be checked before initating the upload.

Comment: Sure I could check this post upload and then reject it but I rather save the user a long and unneeded upload wait and check for this up front.